# Python multiprocess Queue get() blocks

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp, multiprocessing

I wrote a tiny proxy utility (tcp port-forwarder), and now trying to test it.
So my test:

```
def test_forwarding(self):
    route = self.config.routes[0]
    q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    proc_listen = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=lambda q: q.put(str(
            subprocess.Popen(["nc", "-l", str(route.sink[1])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False).communicate()[0])),
        args=(q,))
    proc_listen.start()

    proc_write = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=lambda: subprocess.Popen("nc %s %s < ~/Workshop/port-forwarder/tests/test_data.txt" % route.source,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True))
    proc_write.start()

    proc_write.join(3)
    proc_write.terminate()

    proc_listen.join(3)
    proc_listen.terminate()
    q.join()
    self.assertEqual(open("test_data.txt", 'r').readline(), q.get())
```

but test stucks on `get()` call in assert. Totally messed up, tried all stuff like join/terminate. Any help will be very appreciated.

Here is github repo with sources: [enter link description here](https://github.com/r8d8/port-forwarder)

Answer (score 3):

If you blocked by get, you can

1. use [get_nowait()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get_nowait)
2. or use [empty()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.empty) to check if there is some element in side. if not empty then get, otherwise skip

Comment: I tried to debug in a similar way, polling queue in forever loop - no result. Maybe I using `put()` in a wrong way?

Comment: I found this line broke in your code: https://github.com/r8d8/port-forwarder/blob/master/tests/test_forwarder.py#L36. Seems that your check_output should add a `shell=True` argument, or use list to pass argument, example reference: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output